# Visual Studio is breaking in mscorlib - I really do not want that

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

Usually it just breaks in my own code, but now it's breaking in code I have no control over, nor any desire to see.    How do I turn this off?

[image]

Comment: Post the Exception and the offending code as text, can't see jack in your posted image.

Comment: What option do you have selected in the debugging menu for "Enable Just My Code"?

Comment: @MartinSmith that was it! I had to reset my preferences recently, and "Enabel Just My Code" was not checked.  Back to normal now.

Answer (score 4):

This is controlled by a Debugger setting in Visual Studio:

- Go to menu "Debug" > "Options".
- Under "Debugging" > "General", check the "**Enable Just My Code**" option.

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can mark it so that it can help more people